# What is the proper way to do custom rewriting (with pretty url's) in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I have been wrapping my (coding novice) head around this for so long time now, without being able to make it work.

What I try to achieve is the following:

If a visitor visits

**some-page/?custom_field=something** I want the url to be translated to and shown as

**some-page/custom_field/something**.

What happens now is that when I click on an url like **some-page/custom_field/something** I'm taken to **some-page/custom_field/**.

I do believe my wrong code is in this function somewhere:

```
function myFunction_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^some-page/custom_field/([a-zA-Z-]*)/?', 'index.php?p=421&custom_field=$matches[1]','top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^some-other-page/custom_field/([a-zA-Z-]*)/?', 'index.php?p=423&custom_field=$matches[1]','top' );
}
add_action('init', 'myFunction_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

I'll be the first to admit that regular expressions are fare from my strongest field, so those contributes to my confusion... Does anyone see an obvious error here?

Here, by the way, is the rest of the code I'm using regarding this:

```
$custom_field_query = array();
// add custom_field_query elements
if( !empty( get_query_var( 'custom_field' ) ) ){
    $custom_field_query[] = array( 
        'key' => 'custom_field', 
        'value' => get_query_var( 'custom_field' ), 
        'compare' => 'LIKE' 
    );
}
if( count( $custom_field_query ) > 0 ){
    $query->set( 'custom_field_query', $custom_field_query );
}
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_field_pre_get_posts', 1 );
```

and

```
function custom_field_rewrite_tag() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%custom_field%', '([^&]+)' );
}
add_action('init', 'custom_field_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
```

For the record: Yes, I flush the rewrite rules after every change in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the answer was not what I expected. If I change

```
function myFunction_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^some-page/custom_field/([a-zA-Z-]*)/?', 'index.php?p=421&custom_field=$matches[1]','top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^some-other-page/custom_field/([a-zA-Z-]*)/?', 'index.php?p=423&custom_field=$matches[1]','top' );
}
add_action('init', 'myFunction_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

to

```
function myFunction_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^some-page/custom_field/([a-zA-Z-]*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=some-page&custom_field=$matches[1]','top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^some-other-page/custom_field/([a-zA-Z-]*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=some-other-page&custom_field=$matches[1]','top' );
}
add_action('init', 'myFunction_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

everything works as expected.

Details:

```
p=421&custom_field=$matches[1]
p=423&custom_field=$matches[1]
```

to

```
pagename=some-page&custom_field=$matches[1]
pagename=some-other-page&custom_field=$matches[1]
```